# Insert last row in UITableView with smooth scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a chat bot like application, I have used a `UITableView` with custom cells to fit my needs. Whenever a new message is added, I create and insert a new row and then scroll to the bottom of the `UITableView`. Everything works fine till a certain point, but when the height of the cells change (I have two different type of cells), the animation is messy, it doesn't smoothly scroll to the end and the entire `UITableView` flashes, which is not a good user experience. I have tried a couple of approaches:

1 - Add the data to the data source array and reload the `UITableView`, then scroll to the bottom.

2 - Use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` then scroll to the bottom.

Both of them have the same issue with scrolling. I have used `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to get to the bottom of the `UITableView`

I have uploaded the code of a demo app that represents simulate the same issue [here](https://github.com/tejaskutal/TableViewScroll) so it will be easy to understand. [Here](https://vimeo.com/273272780) is a video of the issue. Any help is really appreciated.

**This issue MAY NOT occur on a simulator, kindly run the demo project on a device.**

**After reading all the comments and having a discussion in chat, I noticed this is happening on the iPhone 5C (10.3.3). I ran the demo on an iPhone 5S (11.3) and the issue does not occur. Not sure if this has to do something with the OS.**

Comment: Your first approach won't work, but your second approach should definitely work. I've checked the code you shared and the 2nd approach is working fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you used a simulator, I suggest you run it on a device. The issue does not occur on a simulator.

Comment: I checked it on an iPhone X. Let me try it on other devices. Which device you are using ?

Comment: iPhone SE, let me check on iPhone 6S too.

Comment: Try to find out where your code spends most of the time. Then you can work on improving the speed. You can use Instruments for this (Command-I in Xcode).

Answer (score 0):

Reloading whole tableview results in messy scrolling instead insert row at last position.

Make following changes in your Action Methods

```
- (IBAction)btnLargeCellClicked:(id)sender {    // To add large green colored row.

    /************ This is the FIRST approach. ***********/
    [arrHeight addObject:@"100"];
    [arrData addObject:@"1"];
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_myTable numberOfRowsInSection:0] inSection:0];
    [_myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self scrollTableviewToLastRow];


    /************ This is the SECOND approach. ***********/
//    [arrHeight addObject:@"100"];
//    [_myTable beginUpdates];
//    NSIndexPath *row1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arrData.count inSection:0];
//    [arrData insertObject:@"1" atIndex:arrData.count];
//    [_myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:row1, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//    [_myTable endUpdates];
//    [self scrollTableviewToLastRow];
}
```

And

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender {     // To add small red colored row.
    /************ This is the FIRST approach. ***********/
    [arrHeight addObject:@"50"];
    [arrData addObject:@"1"];
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_myTable numberOfRowsInSection:0] inSection:0];
    [_myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self scrollTableviewToLastRow];


    /************ This is the SECOND approach. ***********/
//    [arrHeight addObject:@"50"];
//    [_myTable beginUpdates];
//    NSIndexPath *row1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arrData.count inSection:0];
//    [arrData insertObject:@"1" atIndex:arrData.count];
//    [_myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:row1, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
//    [_myTable endUpdates];
//    [self scrollTableviewToLastRow];

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this same as the second approach I have commented out?

Comment: Yeah same as commented code :) what problem you are facing with that commented code?

Comment: The scrolling to the bottom of table is not smooth when both cells are added randomly (in both approaches). Please check out the video, link in OP.

Comment: The video you have posted is the output of the code without comment and the commented one does not produce horrible scrolling...Moreover you can have smoother animation by adding `UIView animateWithDuration:` method

Comment: Yes, it does, if you add a few cells randomly, after a certain point the scrolling is horrible. I even played around with `animateWithDuration`, no luck.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce scrolling issue with second approach; even I tested in device

Comment: Did you add more than 10-15 cells? Both, randomly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172395/discussion-between-priya-and-tejas-k).

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your source, can say *`tableView reloadData`* reloads cells every time, that makes animation more busy every additional cell.
For your goals you should use another system:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

And than, maybe you will need *`scrollToRowAtIndexPath`* at the end too

Comment: The second approach does not work as well, also I don't understand the need to reload the row being inserted?!

Comment: That was theatrical explain, that reloadData makes that. You should use different kind of tableView update, like 'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths' on buttons taps

Answer (score 0):

You would need this, change second approach like below

```
[arrHeight addObject:@"50"];
//    [_myTable beginUpdates];
    NSIndexPath *row1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:arrData.count inSection:0];
    [arrData insertObject:@"1" atIndex:arrData.count];
    [_myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:row1, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [_myTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[row1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

//    [_myTable endUpdates];
    [self scrollTableviewToLastRow];
```

Comment: Doesn't work, also I don't understand the need to reload the row that is being inserted.

Comment: It is not flashes here, i am testing this in iphonex simulator

Comment: Yes, this issue does not occur on a simulator, please try it on a device.

Comment: this issue was occur in simulator too, let me check on device

Comment: You didn't face the issue in video?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172401/discussion-between-tejas-k-and-karthikeyan).